# How to coordinate err.number in different modules, class modules in VBA

Tags: vba, error-handling, module

### I am writing my biggest VBA (Excel) project. It includes several classes, modules. Some of them have error handling, raising error. How can I coordinate the error numbers?

Right now I have in all such modules an independent enumeration for the error values. I searched for how should these number be coordinated on the project level.
What I have found so far is that Err.Number=vbObjectError + 513 + xxx, but nothing if it shall be unique or not. I am afraid that I miss something here.

---

Some of my concerns:
Is it a problem if class1 and class2 have the same Err.Number (and having different descriptions)?
If it is than what is the best practice to prevent it? (If the enumeration is in a different module, then I have a certain dependency.)
Thank you for a guidance on it.

Answer (score 0):

The error numbers are split into two categories.

1. System errors (numbers 0–512). You cannot use those as they are reserved for the system.
2. User defined errors (numbers 513–65535).

> Visual Basic errors (both Visual Basic-defined and user-defined errors) are in the range 0–65535. The range 0–512 is reserved for system errors; the range 513–65535 is available for user-defined errors.

Therefore each error number (and its description) must be unique, corresponding to a single error.

For example:

- Error number: 1001, Description: It's raining.
- Error number: 1002, Description: It's snowing.

That means you have to build and maintain a custom list of errors and raise the appropriate error depending on the situation. For example, if you expect an input between 1-10 and the user enters 20, you should raise your custom error "*Out of bounds*" etc.

Lastly, the error handling is a vital part of an application, so don't be concerned about dependencies. VBA is shipped with an `Err` object to handle the errors. So yes it has a dependency to it but it needs it; it's part of the library and it's job is to handle errors.

Have a read through the documentation, it's very helpful.

[VBA Error Raise](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/raise-method)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the answer @Kostas K. I also studied this: https://chejunkie.com/knowledge-base/application-error-class-vba/#Download.
I came up with one possibility to organize the error numbers and messages.
I wrote a simplified system to demonstrate the solution. There are three classes: class1, class2, class3.
My solution for handling the error numbers and messages would be to include a module with the code having enumeration for the error numbers. The numbers are connected (linked) together ensuring that the numbers are unique and continuous.
It also has a public function for returning the error descriptions. It gives the advantages to handle them centrally.

```
Option Explicit
Option Private Module

Public Enum ErrClass1
    [_First] = vbObjectError + 513
    InitialisationFailed = [_First]
    WrongID
    [_LastPlus1]
    [_Last] = [_LastPlus1] - 1
End Enum

Public Enum ErrClass2
    [_First] = ErrClass1.[_LastPlus1]
    InitialisationFailed = [_First]
    InvalideIndex
    [_LastPlus1]
    [_Last] = [_LastPlus1] - 1
End Enum

Public Enum ErrClass3
    [_First] = ErrClass2.[_LastPlus1]
    WrongClass = [_First]
    CreationFromRangeFailed
    [_LastPlus1]
    [_Last] = [_LastPlus1] - 1
End Enum

Function GetErrDescription(errorNumber As Long) As String
    Select Case errorNumber
        'Class 1
        Case ErrClass1.InitialisationFailed
            GetErrDescription = "Initialisation failed. Is there a Database present?"
        Case ErrClass1.WrongID
            GetErrDescription = "ID is missing."
        'Class 2
        Case ErrClass2.InitialisationFailed
            GetErrDescription = "Initialisation failed. Chech for missing input!"
        Case ErrClass2.InvalideIndex
            GetErrDescription = "Index outside range."
        'Class 3
        Case ErrClass3.WrongClass
            GetErrDescription = "Class does not match with the Standars"
        Case ErrClass3.CreationFromRangeFailed
            GetErrDescription = "Input range is wrong or data missing from the range"
        
        Case Else
            GetErrDescription = "Undefined Error."
    End Select
End Function
```

Furthermore I copied here two test subs: testing how to raise an error and looping through all the error number. I would be thankful for anybody to comment and improve it.

```
Private Sub testRaiseError()
    Err.Raise Number:=ErrClass1.InitialisationFailed, _
        Source:="Test testRaiseError", _
        Description:=GetErrDescription(ErrClass1.InitialisationFailed)
End Sub

'Looping through all error numbers and printing the error messages
Private Sub testErrorEnumAndMessages()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = ErrClass1.[_First] To ErrClass3.[_Last]
        Debug.Print GetErrDescription(i)
    Next i
End Sub
```